# Getting row values for each row in collection

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

I have a collection called Ingredients which I present to the user in a editable table:

```
<div class="container col-sm-12">
    <table id="ingredients_table" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Cost</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{#each ingredients}}
            <tr class='ingredient_row' value={{this._id}}>
                <th>
                    <div class="col-xs-11">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="ingredient name" class="ingredient_name_name form-control input-sm" value="{{name}}">
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th>{{> template_ingredient_cost_field ingredient=this}}</th>
                <th>
                    <button name="delete" class="remove_ingredient btn btn-xs btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </th>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have managed to get save any edits by doing something like this for each item in each row:

```
  "input .ingredient_cost_field_value": (e) ->
    new_value = $(e.target).val()
    ingredient_id = @ingredient._id
    Meteor.call('updateIngredientValue', ingredient_id, new_value)
```

This worked fine while working locally but when deployed it was way to slow. Therefore, I want to change it to use one save button for the whole table.

I have to loop through the table but I don't know how to get the ingredient id for the row.

```
  "click #ingredient_savebutton": (e) ->
    $('#ingredients_table tr').each((i, row) ->
      console.log row
      )
```

The main problem is getting the ingredient id for each row, the other values I can get.

Comment: $(row).attr('value') doesn't work?

Comment: Actually it does.. thanks! I was trying to use .val()

Comment: No problem. I would guess that is because `value` is not strictly a valid attribute of a `tr`.